# Rename/edit a tag in Github after deleting a branch?

Tags: git, github, tags, release

I'm trying to edit [this tag](https://github.com/mojotech/jeet/releases/tag/v2.0) in Github but it's not updating via the Github website.

I tried using the CLI to `git tag v2.0 2.0.0` to at least rename it, but even that throws an error: `fatal: Failed to resolve '2.0.0' as a valid ref.`

I noticed in my .git/config file it still has the `jeet2` branch in it, but I deleted that branch a while ago.

Anyone know if this is the reason it's not working or have any other ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can declaratively set the reference you want to tag.

It should work this way though:

```
git checkout 2.0.0
git tag -a v2.0
```